# How can you access RouteData from the code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-routing

When using ASP.Net routing, how can you get the RouteData from the code-behind?

I know you can get it from the GetHttpHander method of the RouteHandler (you get handed the RequestContext), but can you get this from the code-behind?

Is there anything like...

```
RequestContext.Current.RouteData.Values["whatever"];
```

...that you can access globally, like you can do with HttpContext?

Or is it that RouteData is only meant to be accessed from inside the RouteHandler?

Comment: To create a url just like Url.RouteUrl, you can use the GetRouteUrl-Method in the code-behind file. (I know this is not an answer to your question, but when I google for this problem I always find your question. So maybe it will help somebody. :-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

Comment: Be aware by doing this you're calling into the routing again all over again and this is like N number of requests hitting your route table.

Answer (score 165):

You could also use the following:

```
//using System.Web;
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("{countryname}/getcode/")]
  public string CountryPhonecode()
  {
     // Get routdata by key, in our case it is countryname
     var countryName = Request.GetRouteData().Values["countryname"].ToString();

     // your method
     return GetCountryCodeByName(string countryName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a RouteHandler then you can push the values into HTTPContext during the GetHttpHandler event.

```
foreach (var urlParm in requestContext.RouteData.Values) {
    requestContext.HttpContext.Items[urlParm.Key] = urlParm.Value;
}
```

You can find more information in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx).